# Subclassing builtin types in Python 2 and Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, subclass, built-in-types

When subclassing builtin types, I noticed a rather important difference between Python 2 and Python 3 in the return type of the methods of the built-in types. The following code illustrates this for sets:

```
class MySet(set):

    pass

s1 = MySet([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])

s2 = MySet([1, 2, 3, 6, 7])

print(type(s1.union(s2)))

print(type(s1.intersection(s2)))

print(type(s1.difference(s2)))
```

With Python 2, all the return values are of type `MySet`. With Python 3, the return types are `set`. I could not find any documentation on what the result is supposed to be, nor any documentation about the change in Python 3.

Anyway, what I really care about is this: is there a simple way in Python 3 to get the behavior seen in Python 2, without redefining every single method of the built-in types?

Comment: On Python 2 only the type of `s1` is relevant not the type of `s2`.

Comment: It's kind of similar to the way that `False + False` is `0`, not `False` (`bool` is a subclass of `int`, by the way).

Answer (score 12):

This isn't a general change for built-in types when moving from Python 2.x to 3.x -- `list` and `int`, for example, have the same behaviour in 2.x and 3.x.  Only the set type was changed to bring it in line with the other types, as discussed in [this bug tracker issue](http://bugs.python.org/issue1721812).

I'm afraid there is no really nice way to make it behave the old way.  Here is some code I was able to come up with:

```
class MySet(set):
    def copy(self):
        return MySet(self)
    def _make_binary_op(in_place_method):
        def bin_op(self, other):
            new = self.copy()
            in_place_method(new, other)
            return new
        return bin_op
    __rand__ = __and__ = _make_binary_op(set.__iand__)
    intersection = _make_binary_op(set.intersection_update)
    __ror__ = __or__ = _make_binary_op(set.__ior__)
    union = _make_binary_op(set.update)
    __sub__ = _make_binary_op(set.__isub__)
    difference = _make_binary_op(set.difference_update)
    __rxor__ = xor__ = _make_binary_op(set.__ixor__)
    symmetric_difference = _make_binary_op(set.symmetric_difference_update)
    del _make_binary_op
    def __rsub__(self, other):
        new = MySet(other)
        new -= self
        return new
```

This will simply overwrite all methods with versions that return your own type.  (There is a whole lot of methods!)

Maybe for your application, you can get away with overwriting `copy()` and stick to the in-place methods.

Comment: Right, Python 2 was not consistent here. If you create a `class MySet(set): pass` in Python 2, then `print type(MySet().copy())` gives `<class '__main__.MySet'>`, but if you create a `class MyDict(dict): pass`, then `print type(MyDict().copy())` gives `<type 'dict'>`.

Comment: There's a way to handle at least the non-special methods in a single operation. I'll answer my own question to illustrate how (I can't put code into a comment). But it's still way more overhead that I'd like, with all the special methods to handle one by one.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a metaclass to do all that humdrum wrapping for you would make it easier:

```
class Perpetuate(type):
    def __new__(metacls, cls_name, cls_bases, cls_dict):
        if len(cls_bases) > 1:
            raise TypeError("multiple bases not allowed")
        result_class = type.__new__(metacls, cls_name, cls_bases, cls_dict)
        base_class = cls_bases[0]
        known_attr = set()
        for attr in cls_dict.keys():
            known_attr.add(attr)
        for attr in base_class.__dict__.keys():
            if attr in ('__new__'):
                continue
            code = getattr(base_class, attr)
            if callable(code) and attr not in known_attr:
                setattr(result_class, attr, metacls._wrap(base_class, code))
            elif attr not in known_attr:
                setattr(result_class, attr, code)
        return result_class
    @staticmethod
    def _wrap(base, code):
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            if args:
                cls = args[0]
            result = code(*args, **kwargs)
            if type(result) == base:
                return cls.__class__(result)
            elif isinstance(result, (tuple, list, set)):
                new_result = []
                for partial in result:
                    if type(partial) == base:
                        new_result.append(cls.__class__(partial))
                    else:
                        new_result.append(partial)
                result = result.__class__(new_result)
            elif isinstance(result, dict):
                for key in result:
                    value = result[key]
                    if type(value) == base:
                        result[key] = cls.__class__(value)
            return result
        wrapper.__name__ = code.__name__
        wrapper.__doc__ = code.__doc__
        return wrapper

class MySet(set, metaclass=Perpetuate):
    pass

s1 = MySet([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])

s2 = MySet([1, 2, 3, 6, 7])

print(s1.union(s2))
print(type(s1.union(s2)))

print(s1.intersection(s2))
print(type(s1.intersection(s2)))

print(s1.difference(s2))
print(type(s1.difference(s2)))
```

Comment: A few comments: 1. This would fail to wrap a method called `e()`, but it does wrap `__getattribute__()`, preventing to store objects of the base typ in attributes. 2. This will have a severe performance hit, especially for retrieving attributes.  If you store a list in an attribute, it will be iterated over on every access.  There are more performance problems, maybe too many to point out.

Comment: @SvenMarnach: Why will it fail to wrap `e()`?

Comment: Because for the name `e`, the condition `attr in ('__new__')` will hold.  Admittedly, that's a cheap one, but there are more obscure bugs in this code.

Comment: @SvenMarnach: Ah -- not a tuple without the comma.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As a follow-up to Sven's answer, here is a universal wrapping solution that takes care of all non-special methods. The idea is to catch the first lookup coming from a method call, and install a wrapper method that does the type conversion. At subsequent lookups, the wrapper is returned directly.

Caveats:

1) This is more magic trickery than I like to have in my code.

2) I'd still need to wrap special methods (`__and__` etc.) manually because their lookup bypasses `__getattribute__`

```
import types

class MySet(set):

    def __getattribute__(self, name):
        attr = super(MySet, self).__getattribute__(name)
        if isinstance(attr, types.BuiltinMethodType):
            def wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
                result = attr(self, *args, **kwargs)
                if isinstance(result, set):
                    return MySet(result)
                else:
                    return result
            setattr(MySet, name, wrapper)
            return wrapper
        return attr
```